# How do I :substitute inside a selection?

Tags: substitute, visual-mode, replace

The command `:'<,'>s/search/replace/g` will replace in the whole line of the current selection, but what if I want to substitute only inside the current selection, not the whole line?

*Update*: Found [the duplicate](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/1922/1066).

Answer (score 3):

Use `:'<,'>s/\%Vsearch/replace/g`

From `help substitute`:

> ```
> For the definition of a pattern, see |pattern|.  In Visual block mode, use
> |/\%V| in the pattern to have the substitute work in the block only.
> Otherwise it works on whole lines anyway.
> ```