# How can I quickly replace multiple selections one after another?

Tags: substitute, visual-mode

To format text in LaTeX you need to surround it with curly brackets, e.g. `\emph{}` to render it emphasized. I often need to add commands like that to selected text fragments, nothing that could be covered with a simple `:%s/foo/bar/g` substitution. I already figured out how to do the substitution for **one** selection with the help of [Replace in Visual Selection](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17893/15871), e.g.:

```
:'<,'>s/\v%V.*%V/\\emph{&}/
```

To do this for multiple words, I repeat:

- select
- type `:`
- press <kbd>↑</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Take this as an example, let’s say I want to replace “bayc’” in the first, “minč’der̊” in the second and “oč’ t’e” and “ayl” in the third sentence – and can’t type those special characters easily:

> Irenk’ miayn bołok’ kar-oł en nerkaya-c’n-el bayc’ da hayec’akarg č’-i kar-oł {hamar-v-el. (Ar̊avot 06.04.2006)} \\
>   Agah mecaharust-n ayr-v-um ēr džoxk’-i krak-ner-i meǰ minč’der̊ Ałk’at Łazaros-ě bazm-el ēr hayr Abraham-i {kołk’-i-n. (Nazaryan 2006: 170)} \\
>   Na naew ěndgc-el ē or hakamartut’yun-ě kar-oł en luc-el oč’ t’e mijnord-ner-ě ayl {kołm-er-ě. (Armenpress 25.03.2006)} \\

Is there an easier way to either do a substitution for multiple selections at once or repeat the command faster (something like <kbd>.</kbd> for ex-mode commands)?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your problem. Why can't you search with `/`, use `cgn` to replace the text and then use `.` to repeat or `n` to skip?

Comment: @ChatterOne Because that’s not efficient, I need to replace this word in that sentence and then another one (and *not* the first!) in the next, see the example.

Answer (score 2):

Vim offers at least a couple of different solutions to this problem.

### Repeating an Ex Command

When you issue an ex command, Vim stores that command in the `":` register. You can then repeat this command in the same way you play back a macro: by typing <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>.

Subsequently, just like when playing back macros, you can repeat the command even faster `@` by typing <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>.

### Using a Macro

An alternative is not to use a `:substitute` command at all, and instead to make the edits with a recorded macro. When you are in visual mode, type:

```
qqc\emph{}<Esc>Pq
```

Then, make another visual selection and press <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to playback the
macro. Like in the above, subsequent playbacks can be initiated with <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! A different approach might be possible with [the vim-multiple-cursors plugin](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors), but I don’t want to install a plugin and couldn’t test it.