# Substitute figure by math

Tags: substitute, visual-block

I have a file like this:

```
1 2 3  
4 5 6  
7 8 9  
0 1 2
```

I want to change a block-wise visual selection area, e.g. `5` and `8`. I want to substitute them by multiplying the figures by `0.7` and I want to round  to 3 digits, e.g. `5` changed to `3.500`.

I know `submatch` can work the math, but I don’t know how to define the grouped part.

Comment: Related question [How to replace only within visual selection?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1922/how-to-replace-only-within-visual-selection)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\d*\%V\d/\=printf('%.3f', str2nr(submatch(0))*0.7)/
```

For more info, see:

- `:h /\%V`
- `:h printf()`

---

> Figure could be 5, 5.0, 5.00 or 5.000, 12345678.000, 3 digits at most. How can we define a more general grouped part?

Try a more permissive pattern:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\d*\.\=\d*\%V\d/\=printf('%.3f', str2float(submatch(0))*0.7)/
```

Comment: Figure could be 5, 5.0, 5.00 or 5.000, 12345678.000, 3 digits at most. How can we define a more general grouped part?

Comment: It worked! Using `str2float` is better for float number.

Comment: For easily using, `:vmap <leader>zz :s/\%V\d*\.\=\d*\%V\d/\=printf('%.3f', str2float(submatch(0))*0.7)/`. After block selection, `\zz` if `<leader>` is `\\`, change 0.7 to whatever, then enter.

Answer (score 4):

#### Visual Block: Colon commands will still apply to whole lines

You find in the user manual section 10.3 'Command ranges' following note (almost at the end of [`:h 10.3`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_10.txt.html#10.3):

> Note: When using Visual mode to select part of a line, or using CTRL-V
>   to select a block of text, the colon commands will still apply to
>   whole lines. This might change in a future version of Vim.

A substitute command operating on the whole line would look like

```
:'<,'>s/\(\d*\s*\)\(\d*\)\(\s*.*\)/\=printf('%d %.3f %d', submatch(1), str2nr(submatch(2))*0.7, submatch(3))
```

Alternative, filter lines through `awk`:

```
:'<,'>!awk '{printf "\%d \%.3f \%d\n", $1, $2*0.7, $3}'
```

#### `\%V`

Please note the answer by [@user938271](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22475/1292) using the special atom `\%V` in a pattern. This circumvents the limitation that colon commands work always on whole lines for the `:substitute` command.

Comment: In a data file, it could have many columns. So, by @user938271, `\%V` is more flexible.

Comment: I learned the `\%V` atom today myself. I can agree with people who say that learning vim is a long journey. After 10 years of vim usage I did not know this one.

Answer (score 2):

#### `:B` from plugin [vis.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195) by [DrChip](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VIS): `:B s/pattern/becomes/`

This plugin provides a general command to make all colon commands to operate only on the visual block selection:

```
:'<,'>B s/\d*/\=printf('%.3f', str2nr(submatch(0))*0.7)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `:Substitute` for visual block from plugin [csv.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim#substitute-in-columns)

For single-space separated data you have to initialize the plugin csv.vim manually as following:

```
$ vim mydata
:setf csv
:let g:csv_delim=' '
:CSVInit
```

Now you can use the `:Substitute` command:

Select part of a column with a visual block (e.g. `5\n8`) and then run

```
:'<,'>Substitute \d*/\=printf('%.3f', str2nr(submatch(0))*0.7)
```