# Search and replace text in visual range but not entire line

Tags: substitute, visual-mode, range

I want to search and replace within a visual range just as was answered [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333087/5811761), which uses `:'<,'>`.

But I don't want this to take place on an entire line, only within the selected subset of the line.

For example, I want to replace all spaces within quotes to dashes. I want to turn this:

```
one two "three four" five six
```

into this:

```
one two "three-four" five six
```

But if I select the quoted text (`vi"`) and then use `:'<,'>s/ /-/`, I instead get:

```
one-two "three four" five six
```

because the `'<` and `'>` range marks recognise line positions, not character-within-line positions.

So I changed the marks to use backticks: `` :`<,`>s/ /-/ ``. But now vim gives me the error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: `<,`>s/ /-/
```

I can't afford to do this manually because I have to update a lot of quoted text across many lines. How can I do this? Or is there a more Vim-like way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’m marking your question as a duplicate to help others find the answers. If you have questions about what this means, you can read the help center or ask on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V /-/
```

Where `\%V` match only if the next character is within the visual range.

For more information see `:help /\%V`

Comment: Thanks, from this answer I was able to find this [other post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1922/how-to-replace-only-within-visual-selection) having the same question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)