# Replace only inside visual selection (\%V) by default

Tags: neovim, visual-mode

I would like to always use `\%V` bounds when replacing inside visual selection. How can I make that behaviour default?

I'm currently using [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31149/26459) keymap to achieve that, but I was wondering if there is a setting I can use instead.

I'm using neovim 0.9.4, if there is a plugin that does that, that is fine as well.

Comment: There is no such option

Answer (score 0):

I’m not aware of any setting to do so. There should be plenty of well-documented mappings or commands on this site that accomplish that goal.

I expect that, like `gdefault`, such a setting would interact poorly with plugin code. Besides, sometimes you will *not* want that behavior, so you will need a way to easily turn it off, too.